# db escape in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to be able to use codeigniter db escape because it hashes my passwords OK but in the password row it adds two quotes on either side **Example 'demo1234'**

My salt row does not show it which is OK just the password. On password how do I use my db escape but not having the quotes show up on password row in db.

```
public function addUserToDatabase() {
    $this->load->helper('date');

    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');

    $this->db->escape($salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 9)); // Works OK

    // Salt does not work if don't use db escape.
    $password = $this->db->escape(sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($password)))); // 'demo1234' shows quotes either side off password

    $data = array(
        'user_id' => "1",
        'user_group_id' => "1",
        'username' => $username,
        'email' => $email,
        'salt' => $salt,
        'password' => $password,
        'ip' => $this->input->ip_address(),
        'status' => "1",
        'date_added' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())
    );

    $this->db->insert('user', $data);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked it out I had to do it like this below, all done.

```
public function addUserToDatabase() {
    $this->load->helper('date');

    $username = $this->input->post('username');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $this->db->escape($password = sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($this->input->post('password')))));
    $this->db->escape($salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 9));
    $data = array(
        'user_id' => "1",
        'user_group_id' => "1",
        'username' => $username,
        'email' => $email,
        'salt' => $salt,
        'password' => $password,
        'ip' => $this->input->ip_address(),
        'status' => "1",
        'date_added' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now())
    );

    $this->db->insert('user', $data);

 }
```

Comment: Instead of date_added having mdate('%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s', now()), you can just use time().

Also I would suggest date_added be default in your database :)